# Refresh fragment in Tab layout on any button click

Tags: android, rest, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

In one of my app, I am using tab layout and viewpager with three fragments. In each fragment I am fetching data from server using Java Rest API. This server data depend upon fragment button click. E.g.

[image]
In **process** fragment when I click on **play** button, then that card view goes into **completed** fragment, but it doesn't. when I refresh activity that time it goes, mean when activity close and then start. what should I do to refresh fragment?

Comment: @user1517638 Not Worked !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to refresh fragment like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(YourFragment.this).attach(YourFragment.this).commit();
```

Comment: @fazil you can put this code on button click, after you getting response from server that can refresh your page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Fragment class

```
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
 super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
    // Refresh your fragment here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach

Comment: works but setUserVisibleHint has been deprecated. Is there a newer approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need to update Adapter on model changes, but not whole Fragment.

Comment: yeah, but where?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever operation you want to perform for refreshing fragment just put it inside one method and call it from `onStart()` method inside your fragment, worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one !  Paste this code in your Activity.

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Comment: This does not reload the fragment. Only shows how many pages adjacent to the current fragment will be stored in cache... @Kuldeep wrote the right answer.